# How to write smart contract to check deployed owner is intitiating the contract or not, everytime?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I want to write a smart contract where it would check it is owner of the deployed contract is trying to instantiate the contract or not. And by doing to i want to allow only the owner to call smart contract. How can i do so?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Storage {
  string Hash;

  function set(string memory x) public {
    Hash = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (string memory) {
    return Hash;
  }
}
```

This is my smart contract where i am using setter and getter method.

Comment: Terminology: a deployed contract is already instantiated. Deploying a contract is another word for instantiating. "evoking". Did you mean "invoking? Can you review your wording around "is trying to instantiate the contract"?

Comment: Otherwise, what I think you are looking for is the well-known `Ownable` / `Owned` pattern. You may Google "OpenZeppelin" for examples.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab yeah i am looking for Ownable pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```solidity
contract Storage {
  address private owner;
  bytes32 private hash;

  constructor () public {
    owner = msg.sender; // Whoever deploys smart contract becomes the owner
  }

  function set (bytes32 _hash) public {
    require (msg.sender == owner); // Ensure smart contract is called by the owner
    hash = _hash;
  }

  function get () public view returns (bytes32) {
    return hash;
  }
}
```

Note, that I changed type of hash from `string` to `bytes32` because `bytes32` seems to be more appropriate type for storing hashes.

Comment: Vlad imirov Thanks for exact answer.Do i need to provide contract owner address everytime or its checks on its own?

Comment: No, you don't need to provider it at all.  Smart contract just checks transaction origin.  You implicitly provide your address every time you sign Ethereum transaction with your private key.

Comment: My hash is more than 32, that's why i used string otherwise it gives error. can i store more than 32 positions hash in other way?

Comment: 32 bytes is 64 hexadecimal digits looking like this: `0x0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef`.